# Encoding a Double value to a binary string

Tags: java, encoding, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to encode Double values in an interval (let's say between "a" and "b") to a binary strings (in Java), given the precision (1.234 - precision is 3 in this case) of the Double values. The resulting strings should be equal in length.

I have tried using:

```
String binaryForm = Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(n));
```

Unfortunately, the resulting strings are not equal in length.

Any ideas? The resulting strings are going to be used as chromosomes in a GA.

Comment: Why do the Strings need to be equal in length? Just because the precision in decimal is the same doesn't mean the binary representation will be.

Comment: Of course, you are right about that. The strings have to have the same length so that they can be used in the genetic algorithm as chromosomes.

Comment: Double values are 64 bits, so zero-pad the result on the left to 64 characters.

Comment: It seems that using the piece of code I've posted, negative values result in a 64 char string and positive values go result in a 63 char string. Adding a "0" in front might just work.

Comment: Correction: 62 char string for positive values. But do I have any guarantee that it's 62 for positives and 64 for negatives whatever values I choose to encode?

Comment: @Seb No. Look at the documentation for `Long#toBinaryString`.

Comment: Why would you want to use a GA and not an algorithm that was designed to optimize real values like e.g. CMAES?

Comment: There is an implementation of [CMA-ES for Java](https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaes_inmatlab.html#java). Also there exist other metaheuristics for optimizing real-values: Particle Swarm Optimization is another one. And there also exist real-coded genetic algorithms if it really has to be a genetic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Use suggestion of @rgettman but normalize values between 0 and c = b - a. Thus, the new value (m) for double input n is:

```
m = n - a
```

Then zero-pad to 64. All inputs are positive.